# Get the value in the intermediate model in a Through Relationship

Tags: python, django, model

As I loop through a Prize.objects.all() set, I am trying to get the `quantity` value from `PrizeItem`, but it seems to reference only the GameItem model, not giving access to the intermediate `PrizeItem` attributes.

How do I get access to the Through model's attributes?

**MODELS:**

```
class GameItem(models.Model):
    '...'


class Prize(models.Model):    
    '...'

    item            = models.ManyToManyField(GameItem, through='PrizeItem')  

class PrizeItem(models.Model):       
    #relations
    game_item        = models.ForeignKey(GameItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    prize            = models.ForeignKey(Prize, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #Item details
    quantity         = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=1)
```

**VIEWS:**

```
def gameprizes(request):
    prizes=Prize.objects.all()
    context={'prizes':prizes}
    return render(request, "the-app/game-prizes.html", context)
```

**TEMPLATE:**

```
{% if prize.item.all %}
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
    {% for prize_item in prize.item.all %}
        <tr>
           <td>{{ prize_item.type }}</td><td>{{ prize_item.name }} {{ prize_item.quantity }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: how are you consuming the queryset ? what does your loop look like ?

Comment: Updated to show some more detail

Comment: Ideally I'd like to be able to have the `quantity` available without having to make a huge amount of queries, or making a complex join (also taxing)

Answer (score 0):

It gets a little ugly when it comes to intermediate models in querysets. One way you can address this would be:

```
class Prize(models.Model):    
    '...'

    item            = models.ManyToManyField(GameItem, through='PrizeItem') 

    def quantity(self):
        return self.item.quantity
```

Note that this does lead to additional queries, and you can use `prefetch_related` in your query to optimize

Another option would be to use the template

For game item, you would be doing something like:

```
class GameItem(models.Model):
    '...'

    def quantity(self):
        return self.prizeitem_set.first()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. What the hell with the models?
   ~> Use the @karthikr answer
2. Just prepare in views.py (overwrite query_set)
3. Use (_set ~ join) in html

Have a nice day, don't make it hard, give the hardest part for the strongest (server - database)